# Lookup values from itemgetter in a dict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I'm trying to sort.  The tuples contain strings:

```
connectionsList = [('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('C','D')]
```

The strings in the tuples have numeric values stored in a dict:

```
valuesDict = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':1, 'D':2}
```

What I'd like to do is sort the list by the sum of the values in the dict for the tuples.  Desired output for this toy example would be:

```
[(C,D), (A,C), (C,B), (D,B)]
```

which would have the sums of:

```
[3, 4, 6, 7]
```

Using itemgetter, I can sort alphabetically by position:

```
sortedView = sorted(connectionsList, key=itemgetter(0,1))
```

However, I'm having trouble looking up the values from `itemgetter` in the `dict`.  Running this:

```
sortedView = sorted(connectionsList, key=valuesDict[itemgetter(0)] + valuesDict[itemgetter(1)])
```

gives a dict error of `KeyError: operator.itemgetter(0)`.

How do I create a sort based on the values in the `dict`?

Comment: `sorted(connectionsList, key=lambda x: sum([valuesDict[y] for y in x]))`?

Comment: Though, you'll have to worry about indexing with non-existent keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `itemgetter` instances; you need to call them but they are overkill here.

Just access the dictionary directly with the `key` values passed into a `lambda`. It is a tuple, so add indexing:

```
sortedView = sorted(connectionsList, key=lambda k: valuesDict[k[0]] + valuesDict[k[1]])
```

The `key` argument must be a *callable object*, that takes a single argument (one of the items being sorted), and returns the value you are actually sorting on. `itemgetter()` that returns results based on indexing on the object you call it with; `itemgetter(0)(some_tuple)` would return the first element from the tuple passed in.

A lambda can do the same, in the above solution the lambda returns your desired sum for the given tuple.

Demo:

```
>>> connectionsList = [('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('C','D')]
>>> valuesDict = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':1, 'D':2}
>>> sorted(connectionsList, key=lambda k: valuesDict[k[0]] + valuesDict[k[1]])
[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```

You could also treat your tuple as an arbitrary-length sequence. If you then also account for the possibility that not all values in the tuples are valid keys for the `valuesDict` mapping (taking `0` instead), you could also get your solution with:

```
sortedView = sorted(connectionsList, key=lambda k: sum(valuesDict.get(v, 0) for v in k))
```

This is more general and robust.

You didn't need to use an `itemgetter()` object in your alphabetical sort either; the tuples are already provided in `0, 1` order, so you'd get the same sorting order *without* using a sort key.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look up the keys in the `valuesDict` and `sum` them using `itemgetter` you would have to do something like this:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> connectionsList = [('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('C','D')]
>>> valuesDict = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':1, 'D':2}

>>> idx = 0
>>> sum(itemgetter(*itemgetter(0, 1)(connectionsList[idx]))(valuesDict))
6
```

The `connectionsList[idx]` is the current element that would be passed to the `key` function. So you would need to transform this so that the actual key-function only requires the current element as parameter:

```
>>> def keyfunc(cur_element):
...     return sum(itemgetter(*itemgetter(0, 1)(cur_element))(valuesDict))
>>> sorted(connectionsList, key=keyfunc)
[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```

However that's not really readable compared to a solution without `itemgetter`:

```
>>> def keyfun(cur_element):
...     i1, i2 = cur_element
...     return valuesDict[i1] + valuesDict[i2]
>>> sorted(connectionsList, key=keyfunc)
[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```

So in this case you probably shouldn't use `itemgetter` because it involves much more function calls and the resulting function isn't that nice.

In case some of the keys might be missing in the `valuesDict` dictionary, you should replace the `[]` loopup with `get` calls:

```
>>> def keyfun(cur_element):
...     i1, i2 = cur_element
...     return valuesDict.get(i1, 0) + valuesDict.get(i2, 0)
>>> sorted(connectionsList, key=keyfunc)
[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```

---

Note I generally prefer normal `def` functions over `lambda`s when they become more complex, but that's a matter of taste. In this case it's easily possible to translate them to `lambda`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

first collect sum and tuple in a list:

```
connectionsList = [('C', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('D', 'B'), ('C','D')]

valuesDict = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':1, 'D':2}


tuple_sum=[]
for i in connectionsList:
    tuple_sum.append((valuesDict.get(i[0])+valuesDict.get(i[1]),i))
```

it will give:

```
[(6, ('C', 'B')), (4, ('A', 'C')), (7, ('D', 'B')), (3, ('C', 'D'))]
```

Now sort it and take only nested tuple :

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x[1],sorted(tuple_sum))))
```

output:

```
[('C', 'D'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'B')]
```