# question about custom sorting using key argument in sorted()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to gain some insight in to why I'm receiving an error message.

I'm trying to sort a dictionary using a custom function. I realize I can use lambda to achieve the same goal, as well as sorting the dictionary in to tuples first, but what I'm really trying to do is understand why my function isn't returning a list.

```
sample_dict = {"a":4,"b":2,"c":7,"d":9}

def all_values(x):
    return list(x.values())

print(sorted(sample_dict, key = all_values))
```

Expecting for return list(x.values()) to return a list to be used in the sorted key argument, but instead, I'm given the error message:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 3):

you mean to sort the keys according to the values.

The `key` function is meant to convert the dictionary key to something comparable (if you omit it, it's like passing an identity function, you're comparing on the dictionary key itself). You want to return the value from the key, so it's a dictionary access:

```
sample_dict = {"a":4,"b":2,"c":7,"d":9}

def all_values(x):
    return sample_dict[x]

print(sorted(sample_dict, key = all_values))
```

You were expecting the dictionary to be passed in the `key`, which would have no interest at all. `key` must be different at each call `sort` does.

Using a `lambda` is of course shorter

```
print(sorted(sample_dict, key = lambda x: sample_dict[x]))
```

but passing a real function allows to insert side effects more easily:

```
def all_values(x):
    print("key input",x)
    return sample_dict[x]
```

with that you get an insight of what `sort` is doing (and the final result is printed by the main print statement):

```
key input b
key input a
key input c
key input d
['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```

and now you understand why `list('b'.values())` failed.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to tell the key to only get values, something like `operator,itemgetter` @Jean ?

Comment: not in that case. `operator.itemgetter` doesn't work that way. And you'd still need a lambda / it would be cumbersome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48023356/lookup-values-from-itemgetter-in-a-dict-python

Comment: ah, much thanks. As someone else mentioned, it looks like I was completely confused about what the key argument was actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've been confused by the way `key` argument works.
Essentially, it maps a given function over all elements of your iterable, and then `sorted` sorts based on the outputs of the mapping.
In fact, when you sort `sample_dict`, you are sorting its keys, which are strings:

```
sample_dict = {"b":2, "c":7, "d":9, "a":4}
print(sorted(sample_dict))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and if I try to map `all_values` to this list of strings:

```
list(map(all_values, sample_dict))

# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

---

`all_values` must get a string in input then, like @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggests:

```
def all_values(x):
    return sample_dict[x]

print(sorted(sample_dict, key = all_values))
# ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
```